# Проблема при установке Composer

Tags: php, composer

[image]

В чем может быть проблема при установке?

Comment: прямо же пишет, что не хватает прав на запись

Comment: вывод `ls -l /var/www/my_project/` в студию

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

для выполнения http-запроса не требуется административных прав. поэтому программу *curl* можно (и нужно) выполнять от своего имени. а вот интерпретация полученного программой *curl* php-файла, осуществляющего, вероятно, установку и настройку composer-а, таких прав явно потребует.

```
$ curl ... | sudo php
```

Answer (score -1):

Permission denied.
Попробуйте:

`sudo -u {юзер_для_апача} bash`

Затем надо ввести свой пароль от логина woolf.
`{юзер_для_апача}`  - это тот, кто овнер папки `/var/www/my_project` это обычно `www-data` . Если sudo прошёл - можете повторить попытку установки, если нет - ищите "настройка sudo".

Comment: ну как бы он php выполняет от своего пользователя

Comment: @Naumov Неважно, от какого пользователя у него пхп выполняется. Важно что `/var/www/my_project` у него под другим пользователем. А должно быть под тем-же, которым он хочет композер вкатить И это желательно должен быть тот, под кем выполняется апач - иначе будет путаница.